# iOS MapKit: How to swipe alongside the overlay and get data accordingly

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'd like swipe alongside the overlay on my iOS map so I can obtain data of any given point

examples created in Sketch:

[image]
[image]

How to approach such problem? If you know any pods, libraries to accoplish such thing using MapKit, I'd be happy if you share it with me.

How would you suggest to approach the process of implementation such kind of feature?

Should I focus on creating custom pointer on map with relevant touch gesture recognizer and try to update data in bracket using some kind of callback?

Maybe this feature is already partially implemented and it's just a matter of making these pieces work together?

My code to view the map with overlay

```
 func mapRegion() -> MKCoordinateRegion {
    let initialLoc = self.locations[0]

    var minLat = initialLoc.latitude
    var minLng = initialLoc.longitude
    var maxLat = minLat
    var maxLng = minLng

    let locations = self.locations

    for location in locations {
        minLat = min(minLat, location.latitude)
        minLng = min(minLng, location.longitude)
        maxLat = max(maxLat, location.latitude)
        maxLng = max(maxLng, location.longitude)
    }

    return MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (minLat + maxLat)/2,
            longitude: (minLng + maxLng)/2),
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: (maxLat - minLat)*1.1,
            longitudeDelta: (maxLng - minLng)*1.1))
}

@objc(mapView:rendererForOverlay:) func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {


    let polyline = overlay as! MulticolorPolylineSegment
    let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: polyline)
    renderer.strokeColor = polyline.color
    renderer.lineWidth = 3
    return renderer
}

func polyline() -> MKPolyline {
    var coords = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()

    let locations = self.locations
    for location in locations {
        coords.append(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude,
            longitude: location.longitude))
        print("dodalo")
    }

    return MKPolyline(coordinates: &coords, count: run.locations.count)
}

func loadMap() {
    if run.locations.count > 0 {
        mapView.isHidden = false

        print(self.locations)
        // Set the map bounds
        mapView.region = mapRegion()

        // Make the line(s!) on the map
        let colorSegments = MulticolorPolylineSegment.colorSegments(forLocations: self.locations)
        mapView.addOverlays(colorSegments)
    } else {
        // No locations were found!
        mapView.isHidden = true

        UIAlertView(title: "Error",
                    message: "Sorry, this run has no locations saved",
                    delegate:nil,
                    cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
    }
}
```

**PS. I know this question might be perceived as opinion-based, but I have no idea about better place to ask it. Instead of downvoting, please suggest me a better place with equivalent probability of number of views. StackExchange code review is barely visited comparing to stackoverflow**